# AmCharts Multipledatasets

Tags: file, csv, amcharts, multiple-databases

I am stuck with http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/#theme-none, the creators of the graphic just put a random numbers to fill it, but I would like to load a CSV file which they have a plugin http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-
However, the second graphic is only for 
"Stock" and financial purposses I would like to have the first one populated with a cvs file so I can compare more than 2 datasets.

Can someone help me? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: I'ts not entirely clear what are you having issues with. Are you trying to set up the Data Loader plugin to load your CSV data? Try this tutorial: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-plugin/

Comment: First of all thank you, thank you,  for drawing your attention to my question and I am sorry that I din't make myself clear. I am trying to load data from CSV but the chart they have as example is diferent, the first one has 4 data sets with the same chart type but the second one is a demo for financial purposes with candle sticks as the second data set.  I would love to have an example if you could to knwo how to connect at  least one of the four data sets of the first chart with a csv.

Answer (score 0):

I need to read a little bit more, but I figured it out and Amcharts provides a lot of guide they are really nice and patience.

Below it's a pastie where you can find the whole solution.

this is a brief explanation:

```
{ 
title: 'Title', 
fieldMappings: [ {  // here you set the fields your chart will display
fromField: 'col1', // col1 because my csv has only 3 columns the first one contains the data
toField: 'value' // shows the value
}, { 
fromField: 'col2', // this is the volume to display under the main graphic and that data is on column2
toField: 'volume' //
} ], 
categoryField: "col0", // this is the category which it's display in this case i am using dates so it will display dates and my dates are in column 0 or      column "A" in my csv file.
dataLoader: {  / this is the plugin
url: "data/data2.csv",  // the address
showCurtain: true,  // widgets of the pluging
showErrors: true,   // if there is an error loading amcharts will tell you
delimeter:"\t", // my csv is not delimited by "," but tabs.
format: "csv",
reverse:true  // this is what sort of order you have your data, in my case  from Z to A or major to minor.
}
```

here it't the code:
http://pastie.org/private/bwhvpnb6j8o1jv86cfsg